# Calculating record size include field have 4B real number

Tags: database

Here's a question on my database paper:

```
Each record has the following fields:

Name (30B),
SSN (9B),
Dept (9B),
Address (40B),
Phone (9B),
Birthdate (8B),
SEX (1B),
Jobcode (4B),
Salary (4B, real number).

An additional byte is used as a deletion marker.Calculate the record size R.
```

The answer is

```
R=30+9+40+9+8+1+4+4+4+3+1=113B
```

I can't figure out

1. why only 2 x 9B field are mentioned in the answer when there are 3 defined (I think primary key SSN is the one missing)
2. where do additional 4 and 3 come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Name (30B) 30
SSN (9B) 9
Dept (9B) 3
Address (40B) 40
Phone (9B) 9
Birthdate (8B) 8
SEX (1B) 1
Jobcode (4B) 4
Salary (4B, real number) 4 + 4
Calculate 1
```

Just guessing, there's typo in dept length and your course treats real numbers in a particular way. Please refer to your materials, usually it won't be specifically mentioned that field is a real number (with no typing for other fields) if there wasn't some catch there.

Comment: "Just guessing, there's typo in dept length" Of course it's synthetic example but from my experience SSN and Phone have reasonable, real, lengths while Dept looks like department id that should be shorter (usually). Or Dept could be 4 and Salary 4 + 3 ...
Hope it helps. Have you found any hints on why Salary is sole typed field? Are you studying some specific DB product or just a general theory?

Comment: You should be right on this. The learning materials from my tutor sucks. I still don't know the meaning of real number, but it doesn't matter thanks